# How to find all files with a filename that ends with tilde

Tags: linux

I use Emacs and it sometimes makes backup for edited files. After a few days, I would have a lot of backup files whose name ends with a tilde.

Is there a way to find these files and delete them at once?

I tried this:

```
find "*" -type f -iname *~
```

But it doesn't work. I want the command to work recursively – something like `ls -alR`.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You need to escape from the shell. And you need to specify search path, not `*`

```
find . -type f -name '*~'
```

To delete the files:

```
find . -type f -name '*~' -exec rm -f '{}' \;
```

Comment: @there-is-no-spoon then mark that answer as the selected one :)

Comment: I got to wait 8 min. I will remember. :)

Comment: If you're confident `find . -type f -name '*~' -exec rm '{}' \;` will delete the files for you.

Comment: Ok. How to add to `rm  '{}' \;` `-f` parameter?

Comment: I would personally run `find . -type f -name '*~' > "$HOME"/tilde-files.txt` (this saves tilde-ending files from the stdout of the command to the file ~/tilde-files.txt) and then double-check you're not deleting anything important by looking through the file manually! Only then should you remove any lines that trouble you, and then run `while read line; do sudo rm -rf "$line"; done < ~/tilde-files.txt` to remove the files listed in that text file, especially considering this is a recursive delete.

Comment: how about: `find . -name '*~'|xargs rm` which makes the command follow the line of thinking - 'first find these files, then pipe it to a list of arguments for rm'

Comment: @jjisnow Better use `find . -name '*~' -print0 | xargs -0 rm` in that case. Better still: `find . -name '*~' -print -delete`

Answer (score 7):

You can do something like that :

```
find . -type f -name '*~' -delete
```

If you want to delete also #*# file :

```
find . -type f -name '*~' -o -name '#*#' -delete
```

You can print all deleted files with "-print":

```
find . -type f -name '*~' -delete -print
```

Comment: The second example needs parentheses: `find . -type f \( -name '*~' -o -name '#*#' \) -delete`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is by using grep.

```
lnydex99uhc:javastuff user$ ls
Permutation.java VigenereCipher.java    VigenereCipher.java~

lnydex99uhc:javastuff user $ find . | grep .~$
./VigenereCipher.java~
```

You can also pass any command you want like this :

```
lnydex99uhc:javastuff zatef$ rm $(find . | grep .~$)
```